# sysctl -a doesn't include log_buf_len

Tags: kernel, dmesg, sysctl

I hope to check the value of log_buf_len via sysctl, but `sysctl -a` doesn't  show it, why and is there any other way to check its value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `log_buf_len` is set once and for all [when the kernel is configured and built OR when it is booted with a parameter `log_buf_len=NNN`](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re07.html): you cannot change it after that. `sysctl` generally concerns itself with things that you *can* change in the running kernel: that's probably the reason why `log_buf_len` is not included.

You can find the configured value of `LOG_BUF_SHIFT` by just grepping through the kernel config file (assuming that it's available). For example, on my Fedora 29 system, I do

```
$ grep CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT /boot/config-5.2.11-100.fc29.x86_64 
CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT=18
```

`log_buf_len` is equal to 2^18 then *UNLESS* it has been set through the boot command line.

If that is the case (or if you don't have access to the config file), then the only way I know is to use `gdb` to examine the running kernel, but I haven't done that in many years and I really can't remember all the steps - the main difficulty is to get debugging symbols for the kernel you are running. Somebody else will have to provide  those instructions though (or perhaps provide a simpler method; e.g. it is possible to write a kernel module that prints out the value when it is loaded - there are many tutorials on writing simple kernel modules, e.g. [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html): that tutorial dates from the days of the 2.6 kernel and things may be different today but I (naively?) don't expect things to be very different).